# Como reestrutar um JSON

Tags: json, node.js, rest, oracle12c

Eu criei uma API Node js conectado ao Oracle 12.1.0.1.0c onde conecto e faço a requisção da seguinte forma através do arquivo dbconection.js como mostrado abaixo:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const { json } = require('body-parser');
module.exports = async function retornaPerguntas(req, res) {

    var password = 'dbaadv'
    

    try {
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
            user: "dbaadv",
            password: password,
            connectString: "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=<ip>)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=prd)))"
        });
        
        // Executa a query para retornar as altas
        sql = " SELECT  PER.CD_QUESTAO,  " +
            "         PER.DS_QUESTAO,  " +
            "         PER.TP_QUESTAO,  " +
            "         PER.DS_SETOR,    " +
            "         PER.SN_ATIVO,    " +
            "         PER.NR_ORDEM     " +
            " FROM PERGUNTAS_PESQUISA_NPS PER " +
            " WHERE PER.SN_ATIVO = 'S' " +
            " ORDER BY 6               ";
        result = await connection.execute(sql);        
        
        const objResult = await montaArrayObjetos(result.metaData,result.rows)

        console.log(objResult);

        //console.log(result.metaData);
        

    } catch (err) {
        //mensagem de erro
        return res.send(err.message);
    } finally {
        if (connection) {
            try {
                // Sempre fechar a conexão
                await connection.close();
                console.log('conexão fechada com sucesso');
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
        }
        if (result.rows.length == 0) {
            //Caso retorne nenhum resultado
            return res.send('Não há nada para retornar');
        } else {
            //Retorna todas as altas
            return res.send(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrObjects)));
        }

    }
}
```

A executar essa aplicação a função a cima retorna o JSON nesse formato abaixo por conta da versão do banco de dados.

```
{
    "metaData": [
        {
            "name": "CD_QUESTAO"
        },
        {
            "name": "DS_QUESTAO"
        },
        {
            "name": "TP_QUESTAO"
        },
        {
            "name": "DS_SETOR"
        },
        {
            "name": "SN_ATIVO"
        },
        {
            "name": "NR_ORDEM"
        }
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            8,
            "Em uma escala de 0 a 10; o quanto você recomendaria o Loja A ou amigo?",
            "NOTA",
            "SERVICOS",
            "S",
            10
        ],
        [
            9,
            "1. Em uma escala de 0 a 10; como você avalia o *atendimento A*?",
            "NOTA",
            "SERVICOS",
            "S",
            20
        ],
        [
            10,
            "2. Em uma escala de 0 a 10; como você avalia o *atendimento da B*?",
            "NOTA",
            "SERVICOS",
            "S",
            30
        ],
        [
            11,
            "3. Em uma escala de 0 a 10 como vc avalia o atendimento dos *Serviços C*?",
            "NOTA",
            "SERVICOS",
            "S",
            40
        ],
        [
            12,
            "Finalizando a pesquisa; em uma breve mensagem; informe as principais ações corretivas que você nos recomenda.",
            "OBSERVACAO",
            "SERVICOS",
            "S",
            50
        ],
        [
            14,
            "A Loja A agradece sua participação",
            "OBSERVACAO",
            "SERVICOS",
            "S",
            60
        ]
    ]
}
```

Como eu poderia padronizar em javascript essa estrutura acima no formato padrão JSON como mostrado abaixo?
Tentei algumas formas, mas sem sucesso !!!

```
{
    {
        "CD_QUESTAO": 8,
        "DS_QUESTAO": "Em uma escala de 0 a 10; o quanto você recomendaria o Loja A ou amigo?",
        "TP_QUESTAO": "NOTA",
        "DS_SETOR": "SERVICOS",
        "SN_ATIVO": "S",
        "NR_ORDEM": 10
    },
    {
        "CD_QUESTAO": 9,
        "DS_QUESTAO": "1. Em uma escala de 0 a 10; como você avalia o *atendimento A*?",
        "TP_QUESTAO": "NOTA",
        "DS_SETOR": "SERVICOS",
        "SN_ATIVO": "S",
        "NR_ORDEM": 20
    },
    {
        "CD_QUESTAO": 10,
        "DS_QUESTAO": "2. Em uma escala de 0 a 10; como você avalia o *atendimento da B*?",
        "TP_QUESTAO": "NOTA",
        "DS_SETOR": "SERVICOS",
        "SN_ATIVO": "S",
        "NR_ORDEM": 30
    },
    {
        "CD_QUESTAO": 11,
        "DS_QUESTAO": "3. Em uma escala de 0 a 10 como vc avalia o atendimento dos *Serviços C*?",
        "TP_QUESTAO": "NOTA",
        "DS_SETOR": "SERVICOS",
        "SN_ATIVO": "S",
        "NR_ORDEM": 40
    },
    {
        "CD_QUESTAO": 12,
        "DS_QUESTAO": "Finalizando a pesquisa; em uma breve mensagem; informe as principais ações corretivas que você nos recomenda.",
        "TP_QUESTAO": "OBSERVACAO",
        "DS_SETOR": "SERVICOS",
        "SN_ATIVO": "S",
        "NR_ORDEM": 50
    },
    {
        "CD_QUESTAO": 14,
        "DS_QUESTAO": "A Loja A agradece sua participação",
        "TP_QUESTAO": "OBSERVACAO",
        "DS_SETOR": "SERVICOS",
        "SN_ATIVO": "S",
        "NR_ORDEM": 60
    }
}
```

Tentei solucionar o problema criando uma função montaArrayObjetos que recebe os arrays de CHAVES e VALORES conforme abaixo:

```
async function montaArrayObjetos(objResultColunas,objResultlinhas){
    /*

    'CD_QUESTAO': result.rows[i][i],
            'DS_QUESTAO': result.rows[i][i],
            'TP_QUESTAO': result.rows[i][i],
            'DS_SETOR': result.rows[i][i],
            'SN_ATIVO': result.rows[i][i],
            'NR_ORDEM': result.rows[i][i],


    */

    let tamObjResulcolunas = objResultColunas.length;
    let tamObjResultlinhas = objResultlinhas.length;
    let arrObjects = new Array();
    var obj = new Array();
    var propriedades = "";
   


    var objDados ={};
   
    
    //linhas
    for (let lin = 0; lin < tamObjResultlinhas; lin ++){        
        
        //console.log(objResultlinhas[lin]);

        //Colunas
        for(let cols = 0; cols < tamObjResulcolunas; cols ++){

            //console.log(`cols: ${cols} tamObjResulcolunas: ${tamObjResulcolunas} lin: ${lin} tamObjResultlinhas: ${tamObjResultlinhas}`)
            
            //console.log(`'${objResultColunas[cols].name}':${objResultlinhas[lin][cols]}` + (cols == 5 ? '' : ','))  ; 

            if(cols <= tamObjResulcolunas-1){               

                //obj.push(`'${objResultColunas[cols].name}':${objResultlinhas[lin][cols]}` + (cols == 5 ? '' : ','));
                console.log(`'${objResultColunas[cols].name}':${objResultlinhas[lin][cols]}` + (cols == 5 ? '' : ','));                 

                //arrObjects.push(obj);
                
            }
                                      
        }
        console.log('FIM');
        //console.log(obj);
       
        //arrObjects.push(obj);
       
    }

    //console.log(arrObjects); 
    return arrObjects;

}
```

Quando coloco para printar o retorno dessa função retorna assim:

```
'CD_QUESTAO':8,
'DS_QUESTAO':Em uma escala de 0 a 10; o quanto você recomendaria o Loja A ou amigo?,
'TP_QUESTAO':NOTA,
'DS_SETOR':SERVICOS,
'SN_ATIVO':S,
'NR_ORDEM':10
FIM
'CD_QUESTAO':9,
'DS_QUESTAO':1. Em uma escala de 0 a 10; como você avalia o *atendimento A*?,
'TP_QUESTAO':NOTA,
'DS_SETOR':SERVICOS,
'SN_ATIVO':S,
'NR_ORDEM':20
FIM
'CD_QUESTAO':10,
'DS_QUESTAO':2. Em uma escala de 0 a 10; como você avalia o *atendimento da B*?,
'TP_QUESTAO':NOTA,
'DS_SETOR':SERVICOS,
'SN_ATIVO':S,
'NR_ORDEM':30
FIM
'CD_QUESTAO':11,
'DS_QUESTAO':3. Em uma escala de 0 a 10 como vc avalia o atendimento dos *Serviços C*?,
'TP_QUESTAO':NOTA,
'DS_SETOR':SERVICOS,
'SN_ATIVO':S,
'NR_ORDEM':40
FIM
'CD_QUESTAO':12,
'DS_QUESTAO':Finalizando a pesquisa; em uma breve mensagem; informe as principais ações corretivas que você nos recomenda.,
'TP_QUESTAO':OBSERVACAO,
'DS_SETOR':SERVICOS,
'SN_ATIVO':S,
'NR_ORDEM':50
FIM
'CD_QUESTAO':14,
'DS_QUESTAO':A Loja A agradece sua participação,
'TP_QUESTAO':OBSERVACAO,
'DS_SETOR':SERVICOS,
'SN_ATIVO':S,
'NR_ORDEM':60
FIM
```

No entanto, não consigo separar os registros onde o identificar é CD_QUESTAO e converte-lo em JSON

Comment: É apenas um caso de iterar sobre o array e montar os objetos. O que tentou?

Comment: Eu adicionei uma função que criei  onde recebe o array de chaves e valores e o retorno dela

Comment: Minha dificuldade era justamenta adicionar as propriedades ao objeto, muito boa a sua adaptação, obrigado !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não estou entendendo muito bem se a sua dificuldade está em iterar sobre o seu array, ou adicionar as propriedades ao objeto. Ambos são relativamente simples, e você mesmo já criou um loop para imprimir os valores, o que é praticamente todo o trabalho.

Veja, uma adaptação direta da sua função:

```
function montaArrayObjetos(objResultColunas, objResultlinhas) {
    let tamObjResulcolunas = objResultColunas.length;
    let tamObjResultlinhas = objResultlinhas.length;
    let arrObjects = [];

    for (let lin = 0; lin < tamObjResultlinhas; lin ++) {
        var objDados = {};

        for (let cols = 0; cols < tamObjResulcolunas; cols ++) {
            objDados[objResultColunas[cols].name] = objResultlinhas[lin][cols];  
        }

        arrObjects.push(objDados);
    }

    return arrObjects;
}
```

Basicamente basta criar o objeto `objDados` dentro do loop interno, pois você irá criar um objeto para cada iteração. Então adicionar as propriedades nele, e empurra-lo para o array  `arrObjects`, que é o seu resultado.

Funcionando:

```js
let objResult = {"metaData":[{"name":"CD_QUESTAO"},{"name":"DS_QUESTAO"},{"name":"TP_QUESTAO"},{"name":"DS_SETOR"},{"name":"SN_ATIVO"},{"name":"NR_ORDEM"}],"rows":[[8,"Em uma escala de 0 a 10; o quanto você recomendaria o Loja A ou amigo?","NOTA","SERVICOS","S",10],[9,"1. Em uma escala de 0 a 10; como você avalia o *atendimento A*?","NOTA","SERVICOS","S",20],[10,"2. Em uma escala de 0 a 10; como você avalia o *atendimento da B*?","NOTA","SERVICOS","S",30],[11,"3. Em uma escala de 0 a 10 como vc avalia o atendimento dos *Serviços C*?","NOTA","SERVICOS","S",40],[12,"Finalizando a pesquisa; em uma breve mensagem; informe as principais ações corretivas que você nos recomenda.","OBSERVACAO","SERVICOS","S",50],[14,"A Loja A agradece sua participação","OBSERVACAO","SERVICOS","S",60]]};

function montaArrayObjetos(objResultColunas, objResultlinhas) {
    let tamObjResulcolunas = objResultColunas.length;
    let tamObjResultlinhas = objResultlinhas.length;
    let arrObjects = [];

    for (let lin = 0; lin < tamObjResultlinhas; lin ++) {
        var objDados = {};

        for (let cols = 0; cols < tamObjResulcolunas; cols ++) {
            objDados[objResultColunas[cols].name] = objResultlinhas[lin][cols];  
        }

        arrObjects.push(objDados);
    }

    return arrObjects;
}

console.log(montaArrayObjetos(objResult.metaData, objResult.rows));
```